# confidence intervals of glmnet predictions?

Tags: r, glmnet

`predict.lm` has an option to return confidence intervals of predictions from `lm` models. Is there a way I can obtain the confidence intervals or SE of predictions from a `glmnet` model?

```
library(glmnet)

x <- as.matrix(mtcars[-1])
y <- mtcars$mpg

fit <- glmnet(x,y, alpha=1, lambda=0.01)

pred <- predict(fit, x, interval="confidence") #predict.elnet doesn't have an 'interval' parameter
```

Comment: That's the downside of regression variants like GLMnet, they don't nice statistical properties based on decades of statistical theory. If this were posted on Cross Validated, it would [be a duplicate of this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/402267/7515).